# Regex match and replace in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a file with a number of lines. There may be empty lines thrown in, in between. I want to match all lines that have a specific pattern followed by the empty newline, and replace it with just the line (without the following empty newline). Lines which don't have the pattern but are still followed by an empty lines are to be left as is.

Sample file

```
a + b --> c

c + d --> e
The empty line after this is left alone

e + a --> b

a --> b + c
```

Output file

```
a + b --> c
c + d --> e
The empty line after this is left alone

e + a --> b
a --> b + c
```

I have a pattern that matches all such lines.

```
String linePattern = "(.*-->.*)(\n\n)";
Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(linePattern);
Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(fileContentsAsString);
```

Is there an elegant way to strip the extra blank lines following such lines from the whole string?

Comment: So you want to remove ALL wait space or just the white space after a successful match?

Comment: Empty lines following a successful match.

Comment: Just loop through the lines, copying only the ones you want.  Don't try to make your code too clever.

Comment: Check [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/FWQi4Q/2) and [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/FWQi4Q/1/codegen?language=java). Let me know if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's not that hard:

```
(\w+\s+\+\s+\w+\s+-->\s+\w+|\w+\s+-->\s+\w+\s+\+\s+\w+)[\s\n\r]+(\w+\s+\+\s+\w+\s+-->\s+\w+|\w+\s+-->\s+\w+\s+\+\s+\w+)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/J9uHtj/1)

Executable [sample code](https://ideone.com/7tVv5k)

```
String regex = "(\\w+\\s+\\+\\s+\\w+\\s+-->\\s+\\w+|\\w+\\s+-->\\s+\\w+\\s+\\+\\s+\\w+)[\\s\\n\\r]+(\\w+\\s+\\+\\s+\\w+\\s+-->\\s+\\w+|\\w+\\s+-->\\s+\\w+\\s+\\+\\s+\\w+)";
String string = "a + b --> c\n\n"
     + "c + d --> e\n"
     + "The empty line after this is left alone\n\n"
     + "e + a --> b\n\n"
     + "a --> b + c";
String subst = "$1\n$2";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);
```

Comment: To preserve the newlines, that should be `String subst = "$1\n$2";`, with one backslash.